# Trouble with simple VBO example

Tags: c, opengl-es, vbo

I'm trying to get a super simple GLFW and VBO example running, but I'm stuck. I've used `glBegin` and `glEnd` for other projects, but I'm trying to update my code to work with OpenGL ES 2, but for now I just want to be as forward compatible as possible.

From some examples online, I've come up with the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0

const int width = 800;
const int height = 600;
bool opened = true;

GLuint glTriangle;
GLfloat triangle[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &glTriangle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glTriangle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle), triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void display() {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glTriangle);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0L, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

int windowClose(GLFWwindow window) {
    opened = false;
    return GL_TRUE;
}

void main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        printf("glfwInit didn't work\n");
        return;
    }

    GLFWwindow window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, GLFW_WINDOWED, "Test", 0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    init();

    glfwSetWindowCloseCallback(window, windowClose);

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    while(opened) {
        display();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

This code runs, but all I get is a black screen when I expected to see a white triangle. I've tried to avoid anything fancy like shaders/textures until I at least get something painted to the screen.

If it matters, I'm compiling with: `gcc -o test -lGL -lglfw -lm test.c` on Linux with OpenGL version 2.1 through the Mesa driver.

What am I doing wrong? If I need to specify color information, what is a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `glEnableVertexAttribArray / glVertexAttribPointer` with the fixed pipeline. It *might* work (I'm not positive, I think attrib 0 might alias to the vertex attrib array, but not sure). It's not really correct to do so.

If you don't have a shader you should be using `glEnableClientState` and `glVertexPointer` for vertex data.

The default color is (1,1,1,1), so I think you should be ok on colors for now.

Comment: Aren't `glEnableClientState` and `glVertexPointer` deprecated? That's why I used the other two.

Comment: @tjameson: No; they're *removed*, not deprecated. And so is the rest of the fixed function pipeline. You *need* a shader to render if you want to rely on non-core 3.1+ OpenGL features.

Comment: I guess this is the best answer then given the question. I decided to figure out shaders (not actually too difficult it turns out) and now it's working. Thanks @NicolBolas, that's exactly what I was looking for.