# OpenGL VBO not working

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, vbo

I've been playing with NeHe's OpenGL tutorials for a while until I decided to switch to more modern tutorials. However, no matter which tutorial I pick, I can't even render a single triangle using VBOs and vertex arrays. While immediate rendering worked perfectly.

Take for example the code from http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial03/tutorial03.html, *make*'ing or copying the project to codeblocks to compile it results in a black screen when I run it.
(Note that this tutorial plainly passes the size of the vertex array instead of the number of bytes to glBufferData but even fixing that bug the result remains the same)

I'm currently running Ubuntu (although I had this problem running Windows in the same PC) and the compiler I'm currently using is GCC 4.7.2

I also thought that my video card (Mobility Radeon 4330) could be causing this error by not supporting VBO at all, so here's the output of glxinfo:

```
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV710
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_texture, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_ARB_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_S3_s3tc, 
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_NV_primitive_restart, 
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_OES_read_format, 
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc, 
    GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_MESA_texture_array, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_robustness, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_base_instance, 
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata
```

Comment: To put it simple: no matter what I do (write my own code, copy code from tutorials and tweak every parameter I can think of) my program will only display a black screen if I try to use Vertex Buffer Objects and Vertex Arrays. Whereas using immediate mode (glBegin, glEnd) works correctly.

Comment: http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-4000/hd-4300/Pages/hd-4300-specs.aspx shows that your card supports OpenGL 3.2 so VBO should work fine; I'm skeptical of the drivers, do you have the latest video driver installed?

Comment: I just checked your `glxinfo` output, where you card driver shows it's only 2.1, while for modern OpenGL tutorials, you need 3.1+.

Comment: Yes, GLFW also confirms that my hardware should support VBO. I'm currently using the open source (non official, included with Ubuntu) AMD drivers, I'll try switching to the proprietary fglrx drivers and comment on the results.

Comment: In the same Tutorial 3 from OGL, instead of what comes in the tutorial as `RenderSceneCB` function, could you try what I've posted @ http://pastebin.com/EeRsymgX ?

Comment: Tons of thanks, that solved the problem I've been struggling with for weeks. Could you enlighten me on the workings of this magical solution :P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver for your card [Mobility Radeon 4330](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-4000/hd-4300/Pages/hd-4300-specs.aspx) is currently Mesa which supports OpenGL 2.1 while modern OpenGL tutorials require 3.1+ OpenGL support.

Specifically, although the http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml says that version 2.0+ is enough, some drivers doesn't support it fully. I'd suggest you to upgrade to the latest drivers for your card which would be OpenGL 3.2 and you can happily try out all the exercises from modern tutorials like [OGL](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk) or [Arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/).

Comment: Mesa has supported VBOs for a long time now.  I've personally been using VBOs on Linux with Mesa, I've had no problems with it.

Comment: Yes, it does, but not the `glVertexAttribPointer` for this version. The solution I posted in pastebin uses VBOs too but without attrib functions.

Comment: Looks like this is a dupe, just found an exact dupe of this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633038/trouble-with-simple-vbo-example), after I posted this answer.

Comment: @legends2k: Mesa recently bumped their OpenGL support to OpenGL-3.1 (for devices supporting it), along with some extensions that became core later, up to some 4.2 functionality.

Comment: @datenwolf: Yes, but did you notice that the OP's glxinfo log clearly says that his OpenGL drivers are for version 2.1?

Comment: @legends2k: Well, and I clearly wrote that Mesa will give you 3.x support only for devices supporting it (which also means, device drivers which cover those capabilities).

Comment: @datenwolf: Btw, his card's proprietary drivers DO support OpenGL 3.2, while Mesa doens't seem to, for this card.

Comment: @legends2k: Yes, while the Mesa OpenGL frontend does cover OpenGL-3.2, this doesn't mean, that all the driver backends do provide it already.

Comment: It seems that there are no linux drivers (not even the proprietary ones) that work on Ubuntu 12.10, so I switched back to windows, installed the latest version of the Catalyst legacy drivers and everything works as expected. Thanks for helping.